# How to preview pdf using react dropzone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, dropzone, react-dropzone

Im having a hard time figuring out how to preview PDFs that I'm uploading using `react-dropzone`. PNG and JPG are working perfectly but I would also like to be able to show the user either the pdf itself or an image of the pdf.

Here's my code:

```
  handleImageDrop = (files) => {

    const currentFile = files[0]
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        this.setState({
          imgSrc: reader.result
        })
    }, false)

    reader.readAsDataURL(currentFile)

  }

 render() {

    const { imgSrc } = this.state;

        <div>
          <Dropzone
            onDrop={this.handleImageDrop}
            multiple={false}>
              {({getRootProps, getInputProps}) => {
                return (
                  <div
                    {...getRootProps()}
                  >
                    <input {...getInputProps()} />
                    {
                    <p>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</p>
                    }
                  </div>
                )
            }}
          </Dropzone>
          { imgSrc ? <img src={imgSrc}/> : null}
        </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be as simple as showing an image in a `<img>` tag but you could try some external library to display pdf files. Maybe have a try with [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I used PDF.js to render the PDF files. I set up a custom preview template with a canvas element and added a function in the "init" configuration that triggers when a file has been added and uses PDF.js to draw the first page of the file on the canvas.